# Looking for a Android apk manager which is able to update apps that came from different source (i.e. not google play)

Tags: android

I'm looking for a specific Android app, that I don't know the name of. The app is able to manage and update installed apks (apks that did not came from googles playstore). Unfortunately I did some kind of factory reset and lost all my apps. Now I'm looking for the name of that very app, but couldn't find it. I did some google and froid search.

The app that I'm searching had some kind of **orange background** and was able to **list all installed apps** and their **version**, as well as to start the update process for each (also multi update). I also think there was a config to add apk repositories. The main view was organized with a tabbed view.

**//Update:** the main feature I'm interested in is, the apps ability to update any apk's no matter from where they came from. I.e. the app should be able to update apps installed from any third party source (not google play)

The following apps I can preclude: **google playstore, fdroid, yandex, amazon app store, APKPure**

Comment: While we don't do software *identification* here: if there's any app fitting the features, you'd accept that too, right? There are several [app organizers](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/apps_organize) (incl. app managers) which come close to it, as well as apps around [App Markets](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/apps_markets) you could check while waiting for matching recommendations.

Answer (score -1):

The app that I was looking for is called **[Aptoide](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aptoide)**. It is available for free, and provides access to multiple repositories – which contain apps from multiple sources. It's often possible to update apps from other sources here as well, as long as their signatures match (i.e. they are provided by the same source).

For some background and details, please take a look at [How safe is it to use Aptoide?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/74618/16575) at our Android sister-site.

Comment: Since when does Aptoide update apps "no matter from where they came from"? I doubt e.g. it updates Apps from F-Droid (which are using a different signature), or finds all apps from Google Play / Amazon. Aptoide uses its own repositories, which happen to have a lot of apps found elsewhere – but you should take good care of which repositories you're using, see [How safe is it to use Aptoide?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/74618/16575) on our sister site ;)

Comment: Well in my case it was able update apps i installed from froid as well as apps i downloaded only the apk. Not sure if this is true for every app but in my case it worked

Comment: I see. In that case, the app must have originated at F-Droid and been copied from there – or Paulo fulfilled his promise to integrate F-Droid into the *Aptoide* app :)